# Parse json arrays with ValidatableResponseOptions.body

Tags: java, json, response, matcher, jsonpath

As ValidatableResponseOptions.body [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/2.6.0/com/jayway/restassured/response/ValidatableResponseOptions.html#content-java.lang.String-org.hamcrest.Matcher-java.lang.Object...-) shows you can "parse" a JSON to check whether a value exists (or similar).

Now my JSON liiks like this:

```
[
   {
      "from_name": "Peter",
   },
   {
      "from_name": "Max"
   }
]
```

I want to check if there are arrays with the `from_name` Peter. I tried:

```
.body("[].from_email", equalTo("Peter"))
```

This throws the error `Invalid JSON expression:Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: [ @ line 1, column 27.        [].from_email         ^1 error`.

Trying following also not works:

```
.body("$..from_email", equalTo(shopEmailAddress))
```

or

```
.body(".from_email", equalTo(shopEmailAddress))
```

How is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to parse an array of json instead of a json. That's what the error is telling you. You should iterate on the array and parse each json independently.

You can also stream the array and look for the first case which verifies your predicate.